# NSFetchedResultsController not updating anymore

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an IOS project where i used to have my core data stack set up in my AppDelegate, and was passing the managed object context around as per Apple's example. I have tried changing this to the CoreDataStack project in Github (https://github.com/adamgit/CoreDataStack). I have made what i believe to be the correct changes, but now my NSFetchedResults controller is not updating correctly.

The app uses one screen to add players to the data store and then returns the user to a table view which should display all existing players, plus the one that was just added. Debugging shows that the data for the newly added player is "fault". If i restart the app however, the new player is visible in the table view.
Any ideas?

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is enough to call this when the refreshed table view is displayed:

```
[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:
     _fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest error:nil];
```

A more expensive operation, but usually also feasible, is

```
_fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```